# New Facebook Graph API 2 and taggable_friends: how order the list?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since the new Graph API (v2.0) it's impossible retrieve the list of friends of mine by **/me/friends**.

The only tool to retrieve a list of friends it's using the (useless) endpoint **/me/taggable_friends**

So, how I can order the taggable_friend's returned JSON alphabetically (or other)? I really don't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: If it is useless why are you using it? Sort them after name just like you would have done with /me/friends

Comment: You have to order the names yourself inside your application.

Comment: @WizKid I think it is useless for some reasons (see the discussion https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396) but I still try to use it…
I don't know what do you mean when you say "Sort them after name just like you would have done with /me/friends", can you provide an example? thanks.

Comment: @Tobi order a list of 5000 friends in js is to expansive for my app.

Comment: Sorting 5000 friends should be a matter of milliseconds in a modern browser. Anyway, you cannot trigger the sorting the output on the FB side via API.

Comment: @Tobi I'll explain, I retrieve the list step by step (using /me/taggable_friends?limit=10) so I can't sort the list in js, I need a way to sort them by querystring.

Comment: No. There's no such thing. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#reading

Comment: I understand, but this is absolutely insane. I can do this with fql in a very simple way, but fql doesn't work with this new taggable_friends…

Comment: @GiovanniDiGregorio: I would suggest that you figure out if you can use taggable_friends or not before implementing it.